# Delphi 7 - trying to understand the MVC pattern

Tags: delphi, model-view-controller

I am trying to understand the MVC pattern and this is what I came up with. If you could be so kind and tell me if I did it correctly, suggest some improvments, or diss me for failing completely, I'd be more than happy!

Here's a link to the project (Delphi 7): http://www.sendspace.com/file/ynpgre

Comment: Instead of asking people to download your source (which might not be there in the future?) I suggest you post your question with code snippets here on SO.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the `Observer pattern` first. An example implementation can be found here: http://blogs.teamb.com/joannacarter/2004/06/30/690

Comment: Thanks. So overall is good, but the Observer pattern is missing, right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have rewritten your project to use MVC.

Main project file:

```
var
  Model: TModel;
  Controller: TController;
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);

  Model      := TModel.Create;
  Controller := TController.Create(Model, MainForm);

  Application.Run;

  Controller.Free;
  Model.Free;
end.
```

Model:

```
TModel = class(TSubject)
private
  FData: TStrings;
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy(); override;
  procedure AddLine(AText: string);
  property Data: TStrings read FData; // Do not write to this directly, since it doesn't call notify!
end;
```

Controller:

```
TController = class(TObserver)
private
  FModel: TModel;
  FView:  TMainForm;
public
  constructor Create(const AModel: TModel; AView: TMainForm);
  destructor Destroy(); override;
  procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Refresh(ASubject: TSubject); override;
end;
```

The main form is working as the View, i have removed **all** code from it.

The controller registers itself as an observer and does all the logic:

```
constructor TController.Create(const AModel: TModel; AView: TMainForm);
begin
  inherited Create();
  FModel := AModel;
  FView  := AView;
  FModel.Register(Self);
  FView.Button1.OnClick := ButtonClick;
  FView.Button2.OnClick := ButtonClick;
  FView.Button3.OnClick := ButtonClick;
end;

destructor TController.Destroy;
begin
  FModel.UnRegister(Self);
  FView.Button1.OnClick := nil;
  FView.Button2.OnClick := nil;
  FView.Button3.OnClick := nil;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TController.Refresh(ASubject: TSubject);
begin
  FView.ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    FView.ListBox1.Items.Assign(FModel.Data);
  finally
    FView.ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TController.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender = FView.Button1 then begin
    FModel.AddLine('Hello');
  end else
  if Sender = FView.Button2 then begin
    FModel.AddLine('Hello World!');
  end else
  if Sender = FView.Button3 then begin
    FModel.AddLine(DateToStr(Now));
  end
end;
```

I cheated a little bit with the View <-> Controller relationship, but you should get the general idea :).

- The Controller has references to both View and Model.
- The View knows nothing about the Model.
- The Model knows nothing aboug the View.

PS: A diagram for the MVC pattern (the dotted lines represent Observer/Subject relationships):

[image: MVC diagram]

Comment: Looks great! Thanks. I'm guessing you took both the `TSubject` and `TObserver` classes from the article you mentioned earlier, right?

Comment: Not exactly, they are part of some library code. Basically the `TSubject` has a list of `TObserver`s that can be added by a `Register` method. When the `Notify` method is called on the ` TSubject` it calls `Refresh(Self)` on all observers.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Jens, you've been a great help!

Comment: Great answer to a question asked terribly. Could you please explain what you mean by "I cheated a little bit with the View <-> Controller relationship" so that I know how it should be done properly?

Comment: By cheating I meant that this is actually MVA and not MVC (the View doesn't observe the Model, but the Controller observes the Model instead). This makes the View more reusable and decouples it from the Model. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93adapter

Comment: MVA has several advantages over MVC, so I don't think that it makes sense to use "pure" MVC (which is the older concept) any more.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Thanks for answering. But where exactly is `Notify()` called and which class declares it? I can't understand how the View finds out that the Model has changed (e.g. a line was added with `TModel.AddLine()`).

Comment: Model is a Subject and Controller is an Observer here (Observer pattern). The Model calls `Notify` whenever its `AddLine` method is called. This will cause the Controller to get notified (Its `Refresh` method is called). The Controller then updates the View inside the `Refresh` method.

Comment: With your answer and your comments I finally understood the concept  that I couldn't for so long! And I managed to implement it in my program. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Are you sure about diagram (relationship between model and view)?